# "Unable to remove the file to be replaced" error during File.Replace, if FileSystemWatcher is active and executing a call to Path.GetDirectoryName

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, access-denied

I would like to understand the root cause for this error:

> Unable to remove the file to be replaced.

This error comes while executing `File.Replace()`, and having in parallel in another application an active `FileSystemWatcher`, which as a reaction to the events, is calling `Path.GetDirectoryName()` for the actual element received in the `eventargs`.

The code for the two console applications looks like this:

FileReplacerr:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
internal static class FileReplacer
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test Started.");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(rootPath);
        CleanUp(new List<string> { livePath, tempPath }, -1);
        for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < 10000; loopIndex++)
        {
            WriteXmlFile(livePath + loopIndex, "LiveContent");
            WriteXmlFile(tempPath + loopIndex, "TempContent");
            ReplaceFiles(livePath + loopIndex, tempPath + loopIndex);
            CleanUp(new List<string> { livePath + loopIndex, tempPath + loopIndex }, loopIndex);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Test Finished.");
        Console.WriteLine("Exception count: {0}", exceptionCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ReplaceFiles(string replacedFile, string replacementFile)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Replace(replacedFile, replacementFile, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionCount++;
            string extendedErrorMessage = string.Format("Replacement of original:'{0}' and temporary:'{1}' xml file completed with error code: {2}", replacedFile, replacementFile, ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Exception happened during replace:");
            Console.WriteLine(extendedErrorMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static void WriteXmlFile(string filePath, string elementText)
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 32 * 1024, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
        {
            fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fileStream.SetLength(0);

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { CheckCharacters = false };
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileStream, settings))
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement(elementText);
                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CleanUp(List<string> filePaths, int loopIndex)
    {
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }

    private static int exceptionCount = 0;
    static readonly string rootPath = @"C:\teststorage\";
    static readonly string liveFile = "live.xml";
    static readonly string tempFile = "temp.xml.tmp";
    static readonly string livePath = rootPath + liveFile;
    static readonly string tempPath = rootPath + tempFile;
}
}
```

FileSystemWatcherr:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileSystemWatcherr
{
class FileSystemWatcherr
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = @"c:\",
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName,
            IncludeSubdirectories = true
        })
        {
            watcher.Changed += OnFolderStructureChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnFolderStructureChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnFolderStructureChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnFolderStructureChanged;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("FileSystemWatcher is active");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop watching and exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            watcher.Changed -= OnFolderStructureChanged;
            watcher.Created -= OnFolderStructureChanged;
            watcher.Deleted -= OnFolderStructureChanged;
            watcher.Renamed -= OnFolderStructureChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void OnFolderStructureChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = string.Empty;
        switch (e.ChangeType)
        {
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Renamed:
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
            default:
                path = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Just start the `FileSystemWatcherr` and then start the `FileReplacerr` and you will see the error happening.

The issue happens more frequently on Win7 machines. On my Win10 machine, it did not happen, but running the applications on a virtual machine with Win10, the issue happens many times during 10000 loops.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the root cause?

Up to now, I tried using Process Monitor, but from its output I do not understand what the root cause could be:

[image: Process Monitor output]

If you have an idea how to find the root-cause, or you know it, let me know :)

Comment: Internally, `Path.GetDirectoryName()` calls `Path.GetFullPath()` ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/41e203011152581a6c65bb81ac44ec037140c1bb/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/IO/Path.cs#L151)), which "*unlike most members of the `Path` class, [`GetFullPath`] accesses the file system*" to query file metadata and perform security checks. So you likely can't replace the file while `GetFullPath()` is actively accessing information about the file.